# Opening new form is reseting the design?

Tags: c#

So I have a project with two forms: the MainForm and AnotherForm.
In the MainForm I have a button which should open the AnotherForm. I'm using the following code to do that:

```
private void btnTimeReminder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    AnotherForm anotherForm = new AnotherForm();
    anotherForm.Show();

    this.Hide();
}
```

The problem is, when I click the button to open the "AnotherForm", it just opens a blank form in the WindowsDefaultPosition. All the design of the AnotherForm is deleted (The buttons, images, even the size of the AnotherForm).

I have no ideia why is this happening... Am I using a bad code to open the form?

Comment: Are you sure you are initializing the correct Form?

Comment: How can I check that? sorry, i'm new to c#. I am using visual studio 2015.

Comment: Sounds like the designer code is not being called when the constructor of `AnotherForm` is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that

```
InitializeComponent();
```

is being called in the constructor of your new form.
If you need to change the initial position of your new form, you can use

```
anotherForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

or whichever start position is necessary.